# Keep the redundancy - MySQL SELECT based on a redundant input list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in input list of products. Customer might choose the same product more times. This is okay. I would like to query in MySQL the product table based on the customer's redundant input list - keeping the redundancies and not having them aggregate.

Here is the input list:

> Products (a,a,b,b,c,d,d,d)

I would like to get the price of the products like this:

```
a - 10
a - 10
b - 20
b - 20
c - 1
d - 900
d - 900
d - 900
```

So I would like to keep the redundancy!

I was trying to use the IN and the FIELD SQL clauses, but it did an aggregation, so I lost the redundancy. I used this SQL statement:

```
select * from products where id IN ('a','a','b','b','c','d','d','d') order by FIELD(id,'a','a','b','b','c','d','d','d');
```

What SQL operators, clauses, or whatever can I use to have the desired result?

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to fetch the prices once per product and associate the price with all products in your application code.

Comment: What version of MySQL ?  You could add [ROW_NUMER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to your query to keep the redundancy.

Comment: 10.4.11-MariaDB

Comment: @Shadow - right, I could do that... I was just wondering if there is a simple SQL statement that is processing an input list and not doing any aggregation... to have less lines..

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but did not succeed can you create a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) showing the problem?

Comment: My attempt to reproduce looks like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i86UFipHseF2NjKKGXHFdR/0)

Comment: @Luuk - this looks very good! I just want to awoid creating temp tables per customer...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a derived table:

```
select x.id, count(p.id)
from (select 'a' as id, 1 as ord union all
      select 'a' as id, 2 as ord union all
      select 'b' as id, 3 as ord union all
      . . .
     ) x left join
     products p
     on p.id = x.id
group by x.id
order by x.ord;
```

Note that this will keep products even when the count is `0`.  Also, by being explicit about the order, you can intermingle the `id`s in any order -- for instance `'a'`/`'b'`/`'a'`.

Comment: I have to understand this statement better as it is very complex.. Isn't there a simple clause for this that is using a list as condition...? 'ord' and 'union all' - can you tell more about those?

Comment: MariaDb should allow `VALUES` row value constructor.

Comment: No, there's no simple clause for this; this is absolutely the way to do it (though I think mariadb 10.3+'s values constructor can make it more compact)